# Why does an explicit operator bool let me cast to ANY primitive type?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, c++11, implicit-conversion

```
struct test
{
    explicit operator bool() const { return true; }
};

int main()
{
    test a;
    float b = static_cast<float>(a); // b = 1
}
```

Is this correct to be allowed, or is it a VS bug? If it is as designed, what's the best practice here? Should/can I do anything to prevent this?

Comment: VS2012 supports explicit conversion operator?

Comment: @C.R. in the CTP, yes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks like a VS bug: the explicit operator is not supposed to apply in a cast to a type other than `bool`.

This fails to compile in gcc in both [C++11 mode](http://ideone.com/1oTkxa) and [C++98 mode](http://ideone.com/v9gG9l).

> Can I do anything to prevent this?

You have done what you needed to do - it is a compiler's problem.

Answer (score 3):

Adding a general `= delete` conversion should help your compiler realize the error of its ways:

```
struct test
{
    explicit operator bool() const { return true; }
    template<typename T> explicit operator T() const = delete;
};
```

See it [on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e54f94b0d1589442) (no MSVC :))

```
int main()
{
    test a;
    float b = static_cast<bool>(a);  // b = 1
    float c = static_cast<float>(a); // c = ?
}
```

Comment: VS2012 doesn't support deleting functions.

Comment: @ApprenticeQueue You can use the old C++98 workaround then: declare `template<typename T> explicit operator T() const;` but don't define it. In addition, make it `private`.